# Confirm a popup box outside of the desktop environment?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a script that produces a popup that requires the user to click `[Ok]`. I have another script that can automate this by using `SendKeys`, however how can this be done when the the script needs to be run when the user is logged off? The script seems to rely on the desktop environment being active.

Comment: SendKeys is dependent on the desktop environment like you said to mimic keyboard typing. However, so is the user being able to click "Ok." How can the user click Ok if no one is logged on? Without having more info, and assuming you want your scripts to run when no user is logged in, it seems you need to rethink your scripts so that neither of these (the user clicking ok and sendkeys) is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a tool like [`nircmd`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) that can send a `BM_CLICK` message directly to the button instead of relying on UI/keypresses.

Assuming your message box uses a standard `OK` button and you have `nircmd.exe` in the same folder as your script (or in the system path), the following statement should click it:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "nircmd.exe dlg """" ""The Popup Title"" click ok"
End With
```

If the title of the message box isn't unique, pass the process name as well:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "nircmd.exe dlg ""someprocess.exe"" ""The Popup Title"" click ok"
End With
```